# Reading file and placing into array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, file-io

I'm having troubles reading a file and then placing its contents into an array.  The console says my error is here:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at readFile.readFile(readFile.java:23)
at apples.main(apples.java:6)
```

However I do not now how to fix it.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


public class readFile {
private Scanner x;

public void openfile(){
    try{
        x = new Scanner( new File("/Users/Zachary/Desktop/chinese.txt"));

    }
    catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println("you failed foo");
    }
}
    public void readFile(){
        int y = 0;
        int[] nums = null;
        while(x.hasNext()){
            for(y=0; y<10;y++) {
                nums[y] = x.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.println(nums[y]);
        }
    }
    public void closeFile(){
        x.close();
    }
}



public class apples {
public static void main (String[]args){
    readFile r = new readFile();
    r.openfile();
    r.readFile();
    r.closeFile();

}
}
```

Comment: I think line 23 is `nums[y] = x.nextInt();` where `nums` is accessed without having been allocated.

Comment: Assuming you're using an IDE, why not try stepping through your program line by line with the debugger?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have a `NullPointerException` at:

```
nums[y] = x.nextInt();
```

That is because of this line:

```
int[] nums = null;
```

It is null, so you can't put stuff in it. Here's a simple fix:

```
int[] nums = new int[10];
```

The above code will initialize `nums` so that it is an empty (not really - it's actually filled with 0) array like this:

```
---------------------
|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|
---------------------
```

If you want to be able to add as many numbers to it as you want, you will need an [`ArrayList` (link)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Also, this code will throw an error:

```
for(y=0; y<10;y++) {
    nums[y] = x.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(nums[y]);
```

That is because your `System.out.println` doesn't know what `y` is. Just move the `System.out.println` into the `for` loop so it can "see" `y`. (This is called scope)

Comment: thank you this worked, however i no have an error with line 25.  This is the System.out.println(nums[y]);

Comment: @suggamuggafugga ...what error? "I have an error" is not helpful. Fix for that: just move the `System.out.println` into the for loop.

Comment: @suggamuggafugga I will also suggest do not initialize your loop count out side the loop unless you have really good reason for that.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler error states that the error occurs at "readFile.java:23". This is line 23 of the file readFile.java. I believe that is this line:

```
nums[y] = x.nextInt();
```

The problem is that you declared `nums` as:

```
int[] nums = null;
```

When you try to access an array that is initialized to `null`, you should not be surprised to get a `NullPointerException`.

To fix the problem, you need to create an array object:

```
int[] nums = new int[SOME_SIZE];
```

You will need to provide the size yourself as you have not provided enough information for me to guess the value.

Answer (score 0):

is the inner loop really necessary? you are looping x * 10 times which is really not a good way to assigned data.